# Issue to build sql query to filter data from one table

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I am new to SQL and I have the following table defined in Oracle:

[image]

Basically I need to create a store procedure that does the following things:

Display the code,amount, currency and occurrence fields.

However the identical code that have the same currency add the amount and show them in one row and their occurrence, for instance from that data of the above table the result should be:

1. code: TS-4.1 ,Amount: 150 ,Currency : USD,  Occurrence: 2
2. code: TS-4.1 ,Amount: 25 ,Currency : EU , Occurrence: 1
3. code: TS-2.1 ,Amount: 225 ,Currency : USD, Occurrence: 1

...other result

Any idea how this can be achieved  please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CODE, SUM(AMOUNT), CURRENCY, COUNT(*) as Occurrence
FROM <your_table>
GROUP BY CODE, CURRENCY
```

You can use a GROUP BY.

This would group your entries per code and amount and will display the number of rows that have the same code, amount and currency.

Comment: You forgot `CURRENCY`

Comment: Hi tested the above query but TS-4.1 is occurring 3 times instead of two and not adding them